# Publishing application along with the databse with no need of ms sql on client side c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, deployment

I am new here to this forum so mind if I am asking a question already answered somewhere.

I have made an application in windows form, now I want to implement it onto another client PC. I published it and I can install it somewhere else fine, but the problem is that when there is a database involved I just cannot get it to work. I have tried everything I know, I attached the DB with the setup using the setup wizard creator but I cannot get it to work.

My main question is: How can I publish an application successfully, along with its DB and everything in working condition, without installing MS SQL on the client PC, if possible?

Comment: If you have specified connection string of the database which is poitning to some SQL server on another machine. I dont think you should have any problem. I am not sure, I get the issue. Can you please share the exception you are getting.

Comment: everything is working okay, I just need to find a way to implement everything in one .msi installation file. So the client just installs the application. without worrying about anything else. How to make one .msi file which has database in it, in working condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when using SQL Server, you are running in a client-server scenario, and SQL Server is the server portion.  The connection string stored in app.config would point to the SQL Server, and the user would never need to know anything more about the database.

If your application is designed to be run outside of the network (i.e. 3rd party), you have a couple of options.  First, if you want to use a full version of SQL Server, you can make a client installer and server installer.  The server installer would be for setting up the server side (including the installation of SQL Server), and during the client setup, they would need to enter the name of the database server.

If the client has SQL Server Express installed, you can supply the database file, and do a direct connection to it rather than installing it inside SQL.  However, if the client does not already have Express installed, this won't work.

Finally, SQL Server Compact Edition is designed for running on the client.  You can do a "bin deploy" - that is, copy the SQL CE .dll files with your application, rather than installing the software, and the client can use the supplied database.  If you haven't written the application for CE, this would require some rework.

Comment: Is there anyway with the help of which I can somehow get one setup.msi or .exe file which clients just install on their pc without anyother contribution or effort from my side, just like when we install a game. it just asks me for directory and it installs and works fine. The only way I so far know of deployment is , that, take the application and db file, install sql server on client pc , import the db and run the application , its kind of messy when you are delivering product this way. need help thanks.

Comment: Full blown SQL Server is not designed to be redistributable.  Yes, you can link your msi to the SQL installer, and you could probably script the SQL installer to be silent.  But this is installing a very large application to be hidden by the user.  A full SQL install requires administration effort - it is not just fire and forget.  If you really want a local db with redistribution options, use SQL CE.  That's what it is designed for.

Comment: alright, sure, you mentioned that it would be requiring some rework. Please clarify that rework. I went to Microsoft website and found the SQL CE setup to be of just 2.5 MB, can you please guide me about what rework do I need to do in order to achieve this. Many Thanks

Comment: SQL CE uses a different client library, so all of your client connections, commands, data adapters, etc would need to be moved to the classes under the System.Data.SqlServerCe namespace. (SqlConnection => SqlCeConnection, SqlCommand => SqlCeCommand, etc).  Also, there are some pieces of SQL Server that are not compatible with SQL CE, namely stored procedures.  If you have SPs, you'll need to migrate that logic into the application.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use sqlLite , it just need a bit of modification as it stated by Dave Simione